# Talend - Insert/Update versus table-file-table

Tags: talend

I have been using insert/update to update or insert a table in mysql from sql server. The job is set up as a cronjob. The job runs every 8 hours. The number of records in the source table is around 400000. Every 8 hours around 100 records might get updated or inserted.

I run the job in such a away that at the source level, I only take the modified runs between the last run and the current run.

I have observed that just to update / insert 100 rows the time taken is 30 minutes.

However, another way was to dump all of the 400000 in a file and then truncate the destination table and insert all of those records all over again. This process is done at every job run

So, now may I know why does insert/update take so much time?

Thanks
Rathi

Answer (score 0):

As you said you run the job in such a away that at the source level, I only take the modified runs between the last run and the current run.

- So just insert all these modified rows in a temp table
- Take the min date modified date from temp table or use the same criteria which you use to extract only modified rows from source and delete all the rows from the destination table.
- Then you can insert all the rows from temp to end table.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Hi Sharad, but delete is again a costly operation. I would like to know what is the cause of delay in insert/update process. Or if delete is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your database is configured, it's hard to tell the exact reason, but I'd say the updates are slow because you don't have an index on your target table. 
Try adding an index on your insert/update key column, it will speed things up.
Also, are you doing a commit after each insert ? If so, disable autocommit, and only commit on success like this : `tMysqlOutput -- OnComponentOk -- tMysqlCommit`.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help ;)

Comment: Sure :) Thanks !!